# Box around minted environment

Tags: framed, minted

I'm using the minted package to produce nice looking java-code but I would like to make a box around the code so it is easier to separate the code from the rest of the document.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Here is an example of my document. I'd like the java-code to be inside a box.

: [image]

---

Thanks for the suggestions. Torbjørn T's solution seems to work perfect but some of my code is too wide for the normal width defined by the margins. The minted environment is ignoring the margins (I can't really decide wether or not this is a bad thing) but the frame produced by minted follows the margin-rule.

Would it be best to make the frame ignore the margins or make my code fit into the box (which probably will look pretty stupid with those lines consisting of a few words)?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: How do you want to handle captions?

Comment: Thanks for embedding the image. And I don't really want caption, just a box around the code.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As mentioned by Torbjørn T. `minted` has some options to add a frame. However `minted` doesn't do the frame. This is done by the package `fancyvrb`. The possibilities of frames with `fancyvrb` are limited. If you want e.g. round corners you can use another package like `tcolorbox` or `mdframed`.

The example below shows you the usage of `tcolorbox`. I am using the advantages of `etoolbox` to add a frame around every `minted` environment.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[]{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\begin{tcolorbox}}%
\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\end{tcolorbox}}%
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{latex}
%Preamble
\usepackage[]{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}%
     {\begin{tcolorbox}}%
\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}
   {\end{tcolorbox}}%
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT: If you want to have automatic line breaks with `fancyvrb` you can use the following. Please note line breaks only occur at spaces. A line break has  pre hook in form of `$\rightarrow$`. You can change it, of course. To get the symbol in front of a line I used `lineno`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
%\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lineno}
\def\gobble#1{}
\renewcommand\DeleteFile[1]{}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_fvrb_box
\tl_new:N \l_fvrb_tl

\RenewDocumentCommand \FancyVerbFormatLine { m }
 {
   \hbox_set:Nn \l_fvrb_box { #1 }
    \dim_compare:nNnTF { \box_wd:N \l_fvrb_box }>{ \linewidth }
      {%box to big 
       \tl_set:Nn \l_fvrb_tl { #1 }
       \fvrb_use_tl:N \l_fvrb_tl
      } 
      {%box fits
       \box_use:N \l_fvrb_box
      }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \fvrb_use_tl:N  #1
 {
  \group_begin:
   \null\hfill\vbox_set:Nn \l_fvrb_box
     {\hsize=\linewidth
      \renewcommand\thelinenumber
           {
             \ifnum\value{linenumber}=1\relax\else
                  $\rightarrow$
             \fi
           }
      \begin{internallinenumbers}
        \advance\hsize by -2em
        \hspace*{-2em}\tl_use:N #1
      \end{internallinenumbers}
     }
   \box_use:N \l_fvrb_box
  \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\begin{tcolorbox}}%
\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\end{tcolorbox}}%
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{latex}
%Preamble
\usepackage[]{minted}
\usepackage[fancyvrb=true]{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment {minted} { \begin{tcolorbox} } \AfterEndEnvironment {minted} { \end{tcolorbox} }%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is nice but it has a bug: https://github.com/ManuelRauber/PublicImages/blob/master/Minted-Linebreak-Bug.png When the code line is intended and gets breaked the "first" line will get an arrow, too. Just look at the picture with the ´CSV.foreach`-line. Is there any chance that you can fix this?

Comment: How do you also add a title just on top of the frame, as usual in tcolorbox?

Comment: How would I need to adjust this for `inputminted`?

Answer (score 23):

Referring to the manual, page 9, you can add `frame=single` to the options for the `minted` environment. There are different types of frames, for example `lines`, which only places lines above and below the code.  The thickness can be specified by `framerule=<length>`, and the distance between frame and content can be set with `framesep=<length>`.

You can also define a custom environment using `\newminted{<language>}{<options>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{python}{frame=lines,framerule=2pt}

\begin{document}
Adding a frame for a single code listing:
\begin{minted}[frame=single,framesep=10pt]{python}
import antigravity
print 'Hello world'
\end{minted}

Using the custom listing:
\begin{pythoncode*}{}
import antigravity
print 'Hello world'
\end{pythoncode*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is misleading: I think this picture corresponds to `\newminted{python}{frame=lines,framerule=2pt}` When I run your MWE the custom listing has a single frame (i.e. left and right bars). Could you please correct the code?

Comment: @JodiSchneider Looks like you're right, sorry about that. Fixed.

Comment: I get an error for your second example `\begin{pythoncode}
import antigravity
print 'Hello world'
\end{pythoncode}` works instead

Comment: @orestisf Which error? I do not get an error with the code in my answer. Note that the starred version of custom `minted` environments have a mandatory argument, whereas the unstarred version (that you used) does not have a mandatory argument.

Comment: @TorbjørnT this is weird, I swear I used your example in my code and there was an error but I can't reproduce it right now. Probably made a mistake somewhere before. Sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `\inputminted` you can put the following in your preamble to get the output of [Marco Daniels answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112573/5645):

```latex
\usepackage[]{minted}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\inputminted}{\begin{tcolorbox}}{}{}%
\xapptocmd{\inputminted}{\end{tcolorbox}}{}{}%
```