# break lines in minted code

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, minted

Thanks to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112559/box-around-minted-environment) minted is able to break long source code lines.

It is working really fantastic, except in one case: When already indented code gets breaked into two lines, than line two gets a little `->` which is nice, but it does not get more intended. Unfortunately the first line gets this little error, too. Unfortunately #2 the line number is omitted, since the first line is already seen as a "breaked line".

An example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
%\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{minted}
\usepackage{lineno}
\def\gobble#1{}
\renewcommand\DeleteFile[1]{}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_fvrb_box
\tl_new:N \l_fvrb_tl

\RenewDocumentCommand \FancyVerbFormatLine { m }
 {
   \hbox_set:Nn \l_fvrb_box { #1 }
    \dim_compare:nNnTF { \box_wd:N \l_fvrb_box }>{ \linewidth }
      {%box to big 
       \tl_set:Nn \l_fvrb_tl { #1 }
       \fvrb_use_tl:N \l_fvrb_tl
      } 
      {%box fits
       \box_use:N \l_fvrb_box
      }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \fvrb_use_tl:N  #1
 {
  \group_begin:
   \null\hfill\vbox_set:Nn \l_fvrb_box
     {\hsize=\linewidth
      \renewcommand\thelinenumber
           {
             \ifnum\value{linenumber}=1\relax\else
                  $\rightarrow$
             \fi
           }
      \begin{internallinenumbers}
        \advance\hsize by -2em
        \hspace*{-2em}\tl_use:N #1
      \end{internallinenumbers}
     }
   \box_use:N \l_fvrb_box
  \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[linenos,tabsize=2]{text}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        host => "192.168.229.133"
    }

    statsd {
        sender => "%{datacenter}"
        increment => [ "%{server}.%{project}.%{web}.iis.response. %{response}" ]
        timing => [ "%{server}.%{project}.%{web}.iis.servetime", "%{time-taken}" ] 
        count => [ "%{server}.%{project}.%{web}.iis.bytessend", "%{bytessend}", "%{server}.%{project}.%{web}.iis.bytesreceived", "%{bytesreceived}" ] 
    }
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

The output of it

[image: Example output]

As you can see, the line numbers and little arrows are a mess. Unfortunately #3 I'm not able to fix this by myself. Is there some one who can help me?

Answer (score 35):

Version 2.1 of `minted` has `breaklines` and `linenos`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[linenos,tabsize=2,breaklines]{text}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        host => "192.168.229.133"
    }

    statsd {
        sender => "%{datacenter}"
        increment => [ "%{server}.%{project}.%{web}.iis.response. %{response}" ]
        timing => [ "%{server}.%{project}.%{web}.iis.servetime", "%{time-taken}" ] 
        count => [ "%{server}.%{project}.%{web}.iis.bytessend", "%{bytessend}", "%{server}.%{project}.%{web}.iis.bytesreceived", "%{bytesreceived}" ] 
    }
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very useful! Thank you!