# Box / Frame / Border around quote

Tags: formatting

I have been using minted to tcolorbox and etoolbox to draw a border around source code blocks ([Box around minted environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112559/box-around-minted-environment)).

Now I'd like to do the same for quote blocks, but I am not sure how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Using `\begin{tcolorbox} ... \end{tcolorbox}` should do what you are looking for.  If that does not do what you desire please provide a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: Alternatives are the mdframed and adjustbox packages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments